# Old horror/sci-fi/cult/campy movie, cabin in woods with a big monster with one eye & white hair

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I'm looking for this old horror movie, cult or campy, maybe sci-fi and possibly independent. Definitely before the year 2000.

Cabin setting in the woods, the monster was big, one cyclopean eye, huge mouth with huge bottom lip, didn't have big sharp teeth though.

The monster had white hair I believe, like a mixture between Bigfoot and abominable snowman. It may have had something strange with its vision also.

At the end, a cop/sheriff man came and tried to save them or the last girl but he got killed, then the girl was the only one left and she got into the police car and rammed the monster into a tree with the car, and kept throttling it over & over hard till the monster was dead.

Comment: One eye "like a cyclops" or one eye as in "missing the other eye"?

Comment: Yes, like a cyclops

Comment: In roughly which year did you actually watch this?

Comment: Saw it in like 88-89

Comment: Sounds somewhat similar to FROSTBITER (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116371/?ref_=tt_urv)

Comment: It's a little fuzzy but I believe I saw it in the early 2000's possibly. But the style of the cinematography looks like mid 80's-mid 90's. And it's highly probable that it was a TV only release, and maybe not a theatrical release.